# Can someone explain this VirtualDOM concept?

Tags: javascript, dom, jsx, virtual-dom

I was reading [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@deathmood/how-to-write-your-own-virtual-dom-ee74acc13060) on making your own VirtualDOM and understood it until I came across [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathmood/cL0Lc7au/), specifically line 14, where it says `$el.appendChild.bind($el);`. It looks like he's trying to `appendChild` without any arguments (just uses $el as the `this` value)! I'm so confused. Can someone explain?

Here is the code:

```
/** @jsx h */

function h(type, props, ...children) {
  return { type, props, children };
}

function createElement(node) {
  if (typeof node === 'string') {
    return document.createTextNode(node);
  }
  const $el = document.createElement(node.type);
  node.children
    .map(createElement)
    .forEach($el.appendChild.bind($el));
  return $el;
}

const a = (
  <ul class="list">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
);

const $root = document.getElementById('root');
$root.appendChild(createElement(a));
```

Comment: See [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @jdigital I understand how bind works. but I'd expect something like `someNode.appendChild.bind(window, myDivNode)`, not `someNode.appendChild.bind(myDivNode)`

Comment: `$el.appendChild.bind($el)` gives a function which is executed with each child node as the parameter by forEach.

Comment: @James Thank you! That makes sense. Totally cleared things up.